# Substracting part of cell

Tags: excel

So lets say that in one row i have in 2 cells some data and I want to extract the data after the second `"_"` character:

```
|   |      A     |           B           |                   
|---|:----------:|:---------------------:|
| 1 | 75875_QUWR | LALAHF_FHJ_75378_WZ44 | <- Input
| 2 | 75875_QUWR |       75378_WZ44      | <- Expected output
```

I tried using =RIGHT() function but than i will remove text from this first cell and so on, how can i write this function? Maybe I would compare this old cell and than to do if the second row is empty because maybe function deleted it to copy the one from first? No idea

Comment: Your question is not clear.

Comment: Better to show more examples, in a table form preferably, what is the input, what is expected output. So far it looks like we can just copy first row into second row, would this work btw?

Comment: @Renat That would be good but I need reputation for that.

Comment: I will try again. Imagine you have A1: 75875_QUWR and A2: LALAHF_FHJ_75378_WZ44. I want in B1: /5875_QUWR and B2: 75378_WZ44

Comment: I want to check if the data in cell has more "_" if it has give me that data after secon _ after right. If format is like this DATA_DATA than do nothing. Is this better? @Harun24HR

Comment: @Alena... check this [link](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables). With the result, just paste as code and finish.

Comment: To me it looks like your data has the same length.....If this is the case `RIGHT(A1,10)` will do. If not the case, your question still isnt clear

Comment: @JvdV Not the case, it can have different length.

Comment: @DavidGarcíaBodego Thank you, I have posted it.

Comment: @JvdV That would crop my A1 and I don't need that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
=MID("_"&A1,FIND("@",SUBSTITUTE("_"&A1,"_","@",LEN("_"&A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE("_"&A1,"_",""))-1))+1,100)
```

Regardless of the times a `"_"` is present in your string, it will end up with the last two "words" in your string. [Source](https://exceljet.net/formula/extract-last-two-words-from-cell)

Comment: I would give you upvote too but not enough reputation for that.

Comment: Not a problem @Alena, keep contributing to SO (questions/answers) and you'll gain the repuation needed without a doubt. Glad this helped you out.

Answer (score 0):

Use following formula.

```
=TRIM(MID(A1,SEARCH("#",SUBSTITUTE(A1,"_","#",2))+1,100))
```

[image]

Comment: What to do in case of A1 from my example. I do not want to trim it.

Comment: How to change this MID to RIGHT? xd

Comment: Not always I am going to have x_x_x_x maybe sometimes x_x_x I need something more general...